# Extending Custom Validation-Class

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-4

I've been experimenting with Laravel 4 recently and am trying to get a custom validation-class to work.

### Validation-Class

```
<?php

class CountdownEventValidator extends Validator {

    public function validateNotFalse($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        return $value != false;
    }

    public function validateTimezone($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        return !empty(Timezones::$timezones[$value]);
    }

}
```

### My rules are setup like this:

```
protected $rules = [
    'title' => 'required',
    'timezone' => 'timezone',
    'date' => 'not_false',
    'utc_date' => 'not_false'
];
```

### I call the Validator inside my model like this:

```
$validation = CountdownEventValidator::make($this->attributes, $this->rules);
```

### I get the following error:

> BadMethodCallException
>
> Method [validateTimezone] does not exist.

I've looked up quite a few tutorials but I couldn't find out what's wrong with my code.

Thank you for your help

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Validator::make` you're actually calling `Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make` although the method itself is non-static. When you hit the `Validator` class you're going through the facade and in the background the call looks something like this.

```php
App::make('validator')->make($this->attributes, $this->rules);
```

It then returns an instance of `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`.

You can register your own rules with `Validator::extend` or you can register your own resolver. I recommend, for now, you just extend the validator with your own rules using `Validator::extend`.

```php
Validator::extend('not_false', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return $value != false;
});
```

You can read more on this and on how to register your own resolver over on the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for your help. I've implemented your suggestion and it works great, but I can't get rid of the feeling that a custom class would be cleaner. What do I need to know to understand how I can get this running?

Answer (score 0):

Is that function supposed to be static? What if you remove `static`?

```
public function validateTimezone($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    return !empty(Timezones::$timezones[$value]);
}
```

Comment: Hey Jari, thank you for your help. Removing `static` doesn't change anything unfortunately.